# How to play DayZ without hackers

Tags: dayz-2012

What are the best way to play DayZ without having hackers ruin the game? My hope is that DayZ standalone will solve most of the hacking exploits, but until that day DayZ just does not seem worth playing while hackers destroy ones hard work in an instant.

Are there any recommended "whitelisting" servers/sites or communities? I would not mind paying a modest fee or subscription to help with costs for such an opportunity.

Comment: How is this not a question? It is valid and one in which people could actually gain some useful information. You admins really need to come down from your high horse and ease off on the "close" button before you end up "moderating" yourself out of users.

Comment: Try [chat]. Maybe someone can help you there. I actually chose to close this question as offtopic, because: it is asking people for a catalogue of websites. Secondly the previous could lead to discussions without a definite answer. If you think people close your question on a whim, then you can't be more wrong.

Comment: This sounds more like a shopping recommendation, as you're looking for a server that meets certain criteria.  Perhaps if you re-worded it to something like, "How can I find a server that doesn't have hackers?", it might be more acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry man, there is no answer.

I've been on whitelisted servers, and although it is better, there still isn't much they can do. People will report incidents, admins will sometimes look into it.  You should read the forums on one of the more populated and reputable whitelist servers, such as BMRF. Go to the section for reporting cheating and you will be sadly disappointed when you observe from the admin's replies just how powerless they actually are. All that can be done is to comb the logs to look for suspicious scripting. Imagine having to comb logs for 50 players in just 1 server...it'd be more than a full time job. It's just not gonna happen.

Day Z is an amazing concept and even as broken as it is, it is still an amazing game. I have so many hopes for Standalone, it will be the ultimate experience if they can fix the problems.